# Replacing the string in android?

Tags: java, android, escaping

In my application I am displaying text from database in a textview. The text contains '\r\n'. So I replaced **'\r\n' with empty i.e with ' '.**

My code:

```
String myString = listItem.gettextdata().replace("\r\n", " ");
```

But still the text is displaying with \r\n....where I went wrong? Please help me regarding this....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you putting the string back into the list?

Comment: replaceAll ??, if there are multiple \r and \n...

Comment: have you tried `listItem.gettextdata().replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "");`

Comment: does it contains \r\n, or \\r\\n? i.e. are the backslashes, Rs and Ns actually displayed, or is it carriage returns and line feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this a case where you have to escape the backslash character, i.e.

```
String myString = listItem.gettextdata().replace("\\\\r\\\\n", " ");
```

Comment: I compiled this accepted answer and one of the others and this prints out newlines as new lines instead of replacing them!

Comment: I had the same problem with my answer. You want *two* backslashes, not four.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try a .toString() after gettestdate():

```
String myString = listItem.gettextdata().toString().replace("\r\n", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
    String str;
    str = "hello\r\njava\r\nbook";
    str = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", " ");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Or

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\r\\n", " ");
```

Comment: Apologies, I think the answer that is accepted is wrong! I compiled and ran both yours and the accepted answer and the accepted answer prints out newlines as new lines instead of replacing them!

Answer (score 1):

Use code below :

```
YourString.replaceAll("\r\n", "");
```

Comment: @James: I have run this code and its working without any problem. Please use your string containing above characters and try to execute it.

Comment: Apologies, I think the answer that is accepted is wrong! I compiled and ran both yours and the accepted answer and the accepted answer prints out newlines as new lines instead of replacing them!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
listItem.getText().toString().replace...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String myString = listItem.gettextdata().replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
```